# How can i use use add_plugins_page() and order it on top of the installed plugins sub-menu

Tags: wordpress

I am using the function add_menu_page

`<?php add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position ); ?>`

and i need to put this in order.

I am making a more in depth plugin management page and i was hoping that i could list it under the plugin menu but above the other sub-menu options.

the current sub-menu order is 
    1.installed plugins
    2.add new
    3.editor

I want my plugin to be number 1 and shift all other down one level.

Any help is much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just like you have `add_menu_page`, there is also `add_submenu_page` which you can use.

Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page

Comment: yes, i can add a sub menu page but is there a way to specify the order?

Comment: Declare them in the order in which you want them to appear.

Comment: I want my plugin as number 1 and the other submenu to shift down one level

Answer (score 0):

Just add the position by number to the end of your file.

```
add_menu_page( 'page title', 'menu title', 'manage_options', 'link-to-admin', '', plugins_url('/images/icon.png', __FILE__) 4);
```

In the case above, the menu title will be in the 4th position.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked this a long time ago, but there were no proper answers. Hope this helps you or others - PBM

```
function adjust_plugin_menu() {
// remove the existing plugin menu items
remove_submenu_page( 'plugins.php', 'plugins.php' ); // Plugins - Installed Plugins
remove_submenu_page( 'plugins.php', 'plugin-install.php' ); // Plugins - Add New Plugins
remove_submenu_page( 'plugins.php', 'plugin-editor.php' ); // Plugins - Editor

// add in your custom menu item
$destination = "path/to/your/plugin/code" ;

add_plugins_page (          
'My Plugin Stuff',
'My Plugin Stuff',
'manage_options', 
$destination );

// Put the other menu items back in 
add_plugins_page('Installed Plugins', 'Installed Plugins', 'manage_options', 'plugins.php');
add_plugins_page('Add New', 'Add New', 'manage_options', 'plugin-install.php');
add_plugins_page('Editor', 'Editor', 'manage_options', 'plugin-editor.php');

}

add_action('admin_menu', 'adjust_plugin_menu');
```